# Could not parse componentmeta

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

We're trying to upgrade an old Tridion 2009 site to Tridion 2011 and some problems occur when we're publishing Pages.

Here is a snippet from the cd_storage_conf.xml:

```xml
<Publication Id="78" defaultStorageId="defaultdb" cached="true"> 
    <Item typeMapping="Binary" cached="true" storageId="defaultJSPFile"/>
    <Item typeMapping="Page" cached="true" storageId="defaultJSPFile"/>
    <Item typeMapping="Metadata" cached="true" storageId="defaultdb"/>
</Publication>
```

`defaultJSPFile` references a Filesystem storage and `defaultdb` references a MSSQL database storage. 
And here is the error message from the publishing queue.

```
66560, Unable to store item inside current transaction, 
Could not parse tcd:pub[78]/componentmeta[119939], 
Could not parse tcd:pub[78]/componentmeta[119939], 
Could not parse tcd:pub[78]/componentmeta[119939], 
Could not parse tcd:pub[78]/componentmeta[119939], 
Could not parse tcd:pub[78]/componentmeta[119939], 
Could not parse tcd:pub[78]/componentmeta[119939], 
Unable to store item inside current transaction, 
Could not parse tcd:pub[78]/componentmeta[119939] , 
Could not parse
```

Changing the storageId of the Metadata typeMapping to defaultJSPFile makes the error go away, but we can't make it work to get the metadata into the database.

Comment: What happens if you remove the Metadata from the mappings? (it should go to the database since that's the default).

Comment: Same problem happens. It seems it's trying to do something with the componentmeta in the pre-commit phase, but it doesn't like the input.

Comment: Mixed cd/cm versions? This doesn't seem very "normal"

Comment: Everything is upgraded. So both cm and cd are both running 2011. There  is both a .NET and a Java publication being deployed from the same deployer and it's the Java publication that shows this problem.

Comment: Sorry Kah, never ran into something like this with Java or .NET...

Comment: And this happens with every metadata schema that is published?

Comment: No, not with every schema. I can't pinpoint the exact issue. When I created a simple page/component template with an existing schema and publish the page all seems fine.

Comment: Do you know what is in your Component Meta? Keywords links etc? I have noticed some changes with how Keywords are stored. Perhaps you could post your offending components XML here.

Comment: So, new components with metadata work fine, but existing ones don't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved. It seemed the Tridion.ContentDelivery.Interop.Dll wasn't upgraded in the deployer. I'm still not sure what has changed that the deployer would go through the linkinfo folder in the deployment zips.

To summarize, make sure you upgrade EVERYTHING when installing a service pack or a hotfix rollup.